# xmpp authentication fails in fb chat application for users login through mobile

Tags: facebook, ios5, xcode4.2, xmppframework

I am using xmpp for my facebook chat application.In that some users' authentication getting failed,those who login through mobile devices/showing mobile icon in facebookChat(in browser).
All other accounts are get authenticated and working properly.
If you have any idea about this then please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding the permissions for xmmp as xmpp_login.

Answer (score 1):

He may not give the permissions

Comment: Ya ...U are ryt.I have got the answer,but I forgot to add that here

Comment: @Anand will you Please guide me how to give the permissions ?